# Should I free() the temporary pointer used to store the result of a realloc()?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, free, realloc

So this is on x86 machine running a Debian based Linux OS. I have the following function which is called a lot of times. I am not sure if I should `free()` the `temp` pointer or I can just let the function as it is.

```
int my_function (char *Data, int Data_size) {

    void *temp;
    Data_size = 7000;

    // Allocate a huge array to store a line of the datalogger
    //
    temp = (char *) realloc( Data, Data_size);
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Reallocate Data ERROR\n");
        free(Data);
        return -1;
    }
    Data = temp;

    // Do something with the Data

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't. `free()` is used to tell the OS that you no longer use the memory with the given address. Since you gave that piece of memory to "Data" you shouldn't free it. But you should call `free()` when you stop using "Data" on some part of your program.

Comment: Hey, thanks. So if I use the 'Data' inside the function and I don't need it anymore I should free(Data) and free(temp) before get out of the function?

Comment: Data is a pointer, temp is a pointer too, they point on the same block of memory, so you don't need to free both of them. When the function finishes, temp will be destroyed, but the data it was poiinting to will remain active in memory. Since Data is pointing to that block of memory, you should call `free()` only when you are done using `Data`.

Comment: This code leaks memory. `Data = temp;` doesn't tell the calling code anything about `temp` . C uses pass-by-value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use `realloc` (not simply `malloc`) it looks like `Data` has already been allocated somewhere else, presumably in the function that calls `my_function`. To clear any misconception upfront, the `Data = temp;` assignment will not pass the *updated* value of `temp` obtained from `realloc` back to the caller, since `char *Data` is passed by value.

Now onto the actual question. Does the caller *expect* `my_function` to free the `Data` buffer or not? The code appears to be `free`'ing it if `realloc` fails. If so, it should probably also `free(temp);` if `realloc` succeeds.

---

[ EDIT ] To emphasize the point @mksteve made in a comment, once `realloc` succeeds in `my_function` the `temp` pointer is no longer necessarily equal to the original `Data`, and the original `Data` pointer is no longer eligible to be `free`'d since it may point to deallocated data at that point. Since the reallocated `temp` pointer is *not* passed back to the calling function, it would be illegal for the caller to attempt to `free(Data)` after `my_function` returns.

On a general note, it's always safer to free things at the same level where they were (re)allocated to begin with. Relying on the caller to allocate and the callee to dispose is risky business for more reasons than just this example.

Comment: Yes you should free it, as the original value is broken by the realloc (original value of `Data` will be `free`ed) and the new value is lost - doesn't leave the function

Comment: Just to be clear. So if the caller is expecting the function to free the `Data` buffer in case of error. I should `free(Data)` if `realloc` fail and `free(temp)` if realloc is successful. Just one more thing, is this the right way of doing things or is there a more secure way of handling this type of memory allocation?

Comment: `should free(Data) if realloc fail and free(temp) if realloc is successful.` That's correct. The other point is that `Data` is passed by value, so the caller does not receive the realloc'd pointer back. The caller function must absolutely not attempt to use the Data pointer in any way after `my_function` returns.

Comment: `is there a more secure way of handling this type of memory allocation`. You could for example change `my_function` to return a `char *` and have it actually return the realloc'd `temp` pointer. That way, the caller would have a chance to receive the value of the newly realloc'd pointer, if it needed to further use it.